# Unificar inputs en VUE

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, vuex

Tengo un archivo de vue que me arma un formulario de contacto tipo checkout donde muestra domicilio de entrega,datos de quien recibe,etc.

y tengo un input para calle y uno para el numero pero debo unificarlos en un solo campo "Calle"

Mi archivo que genera este form es el siguiente: (pongo la parte de los inputs de calle y numero)

```
{
    type: 'input',
    inputType: 'text',
    placeholder: 'placeholders.address.line1',
    model: 'line1',
    max: 255,
    min: 3,
    required: true,
    validator: ['string'],
    validationMessages: {
      fieldIsRequired: 'validators.address.line1.required',
      textTooSmall: 'validators.address.line1.required',
      textTooBig: 'validators.address.line1.required'
    },
    styleClasses: 'col-md-6 pr-md-3'
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    inputType: 'text',
    placeholder: 'placeholders.address.number',
    model: 'number',
    max: 20,
    min: 0,
    pattern: '^[0-9]+$',
    required: true,
    validator: ['regexp'],
    validationMessages: {
      fieldIsRequired: 'validators.address.number.required',
      invalidFormat: 'validators.address.number.required'
    },
    styleClasses: 'col-md-3 pl-md-3 pr-md-3'
  },
```

Como unificarlos correctamente?

Comment: Hola. Tenes muchisimas preguntas que se te respondieron y no aceptaste ninguna respuesta. Recuerda que ese es uno de los pilares de la comunidad, si no, no se sabria si la respuesta sirvio o no. Tomate un tiempo para revisar eso. Los usuarios que no suelen aceptar respuestas terminan recibiendo menos de las que quieren. Ademas, aceptar una respuesta sube tu reputación. Ahora llendo a tu pregunta, podrias generar una variable computada que una los valores. Probaste algo asi?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi gracias por tu consejo, voy a reveer las respuestas, justo pude solucionar en otros casos de otra manera pero si es super importante la ayuda que me dan, asi es como llego a esas conclusiones en algunos casos, Te agradezco!

Comment: Si encontraste solucion y no es la que te dieron, responde tu propia pregunta. Tene en cuenta que las respuestas deben ser claras y las preguntas tambien. No dejes preguntas sin responder (en lo posible). Agradece a quienes te ayudaron votando sus respuestas positivamente, y tambien tene en cuenta que aunque puede que tu solucion haya funcionado, puede no ser la optima...

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi una opcion seria una computed properties no probé aun, pero existe tambien alguna manera de unificar los { } que traen todos esos datos? ya que en este proyecto se usa un plugin de vue que te arma los formularios en base a un json

Comment: no se que son esos {} y no se como armas un archivo de vue con esos formatos. eso no es html valido. es alguna especie de json?

Comment: Si, es un JSON pero ahi lo pude solucionar directamente eliminando el {} que contiene number (el segundo que  puse en la pregunta) solamente era eso, y no unificarlo especificamente. Pero me sirvió mucho tus consejos de la plataforma y verlo de otra manera @gbianchi muchas gracias!

Comment: Lo interesante de esta pregunta, y de lo que venis trabajando, es porque armas archivos de vue en base a json... por eso las respuestas capaz que no te sirven y armas tus propias respuestas. Que herramienta usas para hacer los vue?

Comment: @gbianchi lo que pasa actualmente en este proyecto es que se está migrando todo a vue, pero aun hay muchas pantallas en jquery por lo cual hay una especie de fusion entre lo viejo y lo nuevo, es dificil de explicar jaja pero todos los aportes me llevan a esas respuestas que necesito y ya empecé a agradecer con los votos.

Comment: Claro. Pero nuestras respuestas son confusas en base a tus preguntas. Esto que me explicas ahora lo deberias explicar en cada pregunta.

Comment: Oki @gbianchi seré mas claro en mis preguntas referidas a vue. Te agradezco mucho los consejos, siempre son de gran ayuda.

Comment: Ingresa una respuesta a esta pregunta o elminala. El sistema registra tu trayectoria en el sitio en base a tus preguntas, cuantas aceptas, que votacion tienen y puede llegar a bloquearte por algunos dias si ve que no sos un usuario productivo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los aportes y aclaraciones pude llegar a la solucion de que simplemente eliminando el segundo array del schema que contiene a number, era suficiente dado que solamente con el input calle ya bastaba para ese formulario.